# Check microphone level and change accordingly via script

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-command-prompt

I am trying to check what the existing volume on client workstations is and set to x (let's say x = 16.5).

I figured out how to set the volume via cli which is using nircmd. To be specific:
***nircmd.exe setsysvolume 16 microphone***

Now, there is really no way for me to check what the existing microphone level is as it keeps on fluctuating on my client machines. So, I am really looking for a way to check if the microphone level is not set to 16.5, then change it to this.

Background: I need to set all my workstations to have their microphone level to the 16.5. It has a tendency to alter based on the microphone type and other factors. Any suggestions or better ideas to do this?

Comment: If you want really useful suggestions, please explain what you're trying to do, and why. Otherwise, you can't get better than putting that command of yours to task scheduler to run every minute...

Comment: Wouldn't your your command set them to 16.5 regardless of what they currently are? So why check in the first place? Just use your script to set them to 16.5.